# Inserting data with SELECT into new column

Tags: sqlite

I have a table of data built from a file inventory. I then want to add a categorical column so that I may easily perform `GROUP BY`.

How things start:

```
SELECT COUNT(fullpath) FROM data;

12395
```

I use the column `fullpath` a lot so I create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX "index" ON data (fullpath);
```

I then add the column:

```
ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN 'Sub' VARCHAR(20);
```

Insert values into the `Sub` column based on the `fullpath`:

```
insert into data(Sub)
select case
    when fullpath like '%subA%' then 'subA'
    when fullpath like '%subB%' then 'subB'
    else 'neither' end
from data;
```

Check the number of rows again:

```
SELECT COUNT(fullpath) FROM data;

24790
```

I don't understand the syntax and the operations. Do I need to join or something to respect the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying several iterations and some joins, I realized that `insert` is ever only going to add rows and not `update` them.

Switching my search to `update` SQL multiple rows, lead to an easy solution:

```
UPDATE data
    set Sub = CASE
        WHEN fullpath LIKE '%subA%' THEN 'subA'
        WHEN fullpath LIKE '%subB%' THEN 'subB'
        ELSE 'neither' END;
```

Comment: You are right, INSERT is for inserting (new) rows only. You wanted to populate a column for existing rows, i.e. update them – hence UPDATE. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

You already solved your main problem!

But I want to suggest you to create a new table for `sub` and maybe also for `fullpath`, because you store the same values again and again in this row.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE path (id integer, name varchar(100));
```

Then populate it with a `SELECT` and add the ID to the main table!

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. Are you saying I should normalize my table ?   I think that makes sense as this table grows. For now it's small and it's easier not to write joins. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: correct! Normalized tables are always better! If the paths are long, a lot of space is wasted. If you want to select all files from one folder, it will be much faster.